# Scatter data fitting the best line and showing the uncertainty associated with the slope and intercept

Tags: python

I have a bunch of scatter data and I want to reproduce a figure like the attached figure which is showing the R value of the best fit line, and the equation of the best fit line, which has also the error of the slope and intercept in red within the parentheses preceded by +- sign. Please note that the scatter data have some error bars I want a method to take into account the error bars as well, when fitting the best line.

I am not sure for the error part of the slope and intercept should we use bootstrapping?

Could someone please help me out to exactly reproduce the attached figure with a bunch of random x, and y, with some error bars?

Many thanks!
[image]